# How to check for duplicate text entries in form with multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, duplicates, textinput

I tried to create a form with two pages, and I was wondering if is there any way to check for duplicate text entries on different pages.

In my case, I would like to check if the first field from the first page has the same value as the first field from second page and send an alert before submitting the form.

Here is the code : https://codepen.io/ceres999/pen/ExVGdVq

For example, if I type in " **hello** " in both first fields from both pages send the alert " **Duplicate values!** ".

Considering that I already have an `onsubmit` function, what would be the way to check the two entries?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the entry from form 1 and check it with the entry from form 2

```
text1.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
value1 = e.target.value; 
});

text3.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
value3 = e.target.value; 
 }); 
if(value1!==value3){
console.log('values not same')
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me and I'm not sure why.